# Issues with Wide Characters in C++

Tags: c++, wstring, wchar

I have a program that is meant to read in a text file of words (each on a separate line), and then print out a random word from that file. It also gives you the ability to select a non-English language (e.g., Greek or Russian). Because of the latter condition, I use `std::wstring` to capture the text. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: word [lang]" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tlang: Choose from de,en,es,fr,gr,it,la,ru" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string file = static_cast<std::string>("C:\\util_bin\\data\\words_") + static_cast<std::string>(argv[1]) + static_cast<std::string>(".txt");
    std::wfstream fin(file, std::wifstream::in);

    std::vector<std::wstring> data;
    std::wstring line;
    while (std::getline(fin, line))
        data.push_back(line);
    int size = data.size();

    boost::random::random_device rd;
    boost::random::mt19937 mt(rd());
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, size - 1);

    std::wcout << data[dist(mt)] << std::endl;
}
```

This code compiles just fine, however when I run it with Russian (for instance), I just get garbage text:

```
C:\util_bin>word ru
������������

C:\util_bin>
```

I'm not all that familiar with the ins and outs of wide characters in C++, so I can't really discern what's going wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the Windows console is set to display characters in the encoding used by `std:wstring`?

Comment: I did set `chcp' in the Command Prompt to 65001. Still gives me the strings of �.

Comment: `chcp 65001` enables (rudimentary) UTF-8 decoding. See Vada Poché's answer.

Comment: Have you looked at Joel Spolsky's Unicode article

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess you're using Visual Studio. This is a quirk of the implementation of `std::basic_filebuf` in Windows. From [the relevant MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzf8k3z8.aspx):

> Objects of type basic_filebuf are created with an internal buffer of type `char *` regardless of the `char_type` specified by the type parameter `Elem`. This means that a Unicode string (containing `wchar_t` characters) will be converted to an ANSI string (containing char characters) before it is written to the internal buffer. To store Unicode strings in the buffer, create a new buffer of type `wchar_t` and set it using the `basic_streambuf::pubsetbuf()` method.

As it was explained to me, the filebuf is implemented with a `FILE*`; there is an internal flag that performs the ANSI conversion whether you want it or not, and you can't clear. the flag except by allocating and setting your own buffer (via `pubsetbuf`). Putting a `codecvt` in your locale won't do it.  It has to happen right after a successful file open.  Really, infuriatingly intrusive. I wound up having to write a wrapper class ( which wasn't so bad, as it gave you the ability to store the file name before opening).

You can also open the file with `std::binary`. Some people recommend that you always do that. But opening the file that way probably makes you do your own code conversions before inserting into a stream or extracting from it.

Comment: I'm actually using MinGW, but this is an interesting analysis nonetheless.

Comment: @ MrM21632 If you're getting the error even after using the answer you accepted ( you did comment that), then perhaps the MinGW implementation uses the same Windows implementation of FILE and you should try one of these workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

After you create instantiate your `wfstream` object, call `imbue` on it like this:

```
fin.imbue( std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>) );
```

Comment: I'm getting errors when I add that line of code, namely that empty() isn't a member of std::locale. And yes, I did #include <locale>.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've not done `#include <codecvt>` and it's required to call `std::codecvt_utf8<T>` which we're using within the call to `fin.imbue()`

Comment: @VadaPoché Isn't `std::locale::empty()` a non standard extension?

Comment: Okay, I have successfully embued using `std::locale::empty()' through Visual Studio (I've started using it explicitly for this program!). I'm still having issues. I will update the initial post sometime tomorrow with new details.